# What is the difference between char **ptr and char *ptr[] in C?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void display(int n, char *str[])
{
  int i=0;
  while(i<n) printf("%s ",str[i++]);
}
int main()
{
  display(1,"Hello");return 0;
}
```

when I run this above code I get warnings as

```
    arr.c: In function 'main':
    arr.c:11:12: warning: passing argument 2 of 'display' from incompatible         pointer
    type
    display(1,"hello");
            ^
    arr.c:3:6: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char *'
    void display(int n,char *str[])
```

But then how is it different from

```
    int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

And what is the difference between

```
    char **argv and char *argv[]
```

I am strictly not asking about something like char *argv[100]

Comment: `"Hello"` is not a `char**` or a `char*[]`.

Comment: "Hello" is a const char*, your display function is expecting a pointer to a pointer to a char.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889289/2d-arrays-and-pointers-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `char **ptr` is a double pointer (pointer to a pointer) of char while `char *ptr[]` is an open array of pointer to char.

According to [cdel](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/), char `**p;` gives the result of "declare p as pointer to pointer to char" while char `*p[];` gives "declare p as array of pointer to char."

Character strings are always arrays, and arrays are generally always pointers, so the two are generally equivalent which means that `**ptr` = `*ptr[]`.  What you end up with is an array of an array of chars, or an array of strings.  Take `main()` for instance:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
      {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "some string") == 0) do something;
      }

    Do some stuff;

    return(0);
  }
```

Another way to declare it is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Programmatically, it's easier to understand `*ptr[]` than `**ptr`.

Comment: Well thanks a lot guys for your support and sharing your knowledge which was of immense help to me. Finally the pointers are clear to me now.

Comment: To really thank us, if there's an answer that you like mark it as the answer and give upvotes, if you can.

Answer (score 3):

As a parameter of a function both `char **ptr` and `char *ptr[]` are equivalent, otherwise they are different. Former is *a pointer to pointer to a `char`* while latter is *an array of pointers to `char`*.

When a string literal is passed to a function, then pointer to its first character (`char *` type) is passed. You need to change the function's second parameter to `char *str`.

```
void display(int n, char *str)  
{
    // Function body
}
```